# Altering a user's password through PhpPGAdmin

Tags: postgresql, passwords, reset

I've been asked by a friend to help him reset his password for a website that uses a PostgresSQL database. So, I've logged in to phpPgAdmin and there under Schemas>Public>Tables>users>Columns there's one called "passwd'. I can see the hash values, but I don't understand how to edit them in order to reset the password.

Can someone help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: are u trying to change the password of the postgres db user or an user in your website?

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to know how the password has been encrypted.. it may be an MD5 or some salt string.
You can do some random checking like create an MD5 of a known string and update the column.

The better option to to create a new user via website UI and then copy+paste the `passwd` of the new user to the old one.

Comment: Unfortunately the website doesn't offer the option to create new user outside of the admin panel - to which I have lost access.

Comment: then you should try your luck with updating the row with a known MD5 string.

Answer (score 0):

If You have access as superuser (postgres user). You can reset the password using `alter role user_name with encrypted password 'newpass';`

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I'm on a shared webhosting and I only have access to phpPgAdmin. Is there a way to alter the password through it?